# Windows Vista file permissions does not inherit when copying to a network share

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions, windows-vista, ntfs, file-permissions

I've got a network share with specific permissions on a subfolder (e.g. access to developers and freelancers). A designer copied PNG files from his local system to the network share.

These files didn't inherit the folder permissions, but only gave access to Administrators.

Is this a setting somewhere to restrict access, and can it be avoided?
The local system uses Vista, the server uses Windows 2003.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy operations should always inherit the destination folder's permissions. Move operations should preseve the file permissions. However, if the person moving the files does not have permission to set permission (if they only have Modify, not Full Controll) it will effective inherit the folder's permissions.

Comment: So logically, if vdboor *removes* 'Full control' permission from his users, it may fix this behavior?

Comment: @Chris, if the developer actually copied the file, like he said he did, we wouldn't have to fudge permissions. But yeah, removing their ability to set file permissions would force the files to inherit.